# Get referer url from google cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud API function that is built on Node.js. I want to find the source of API request. I mean request header referer. I have tried using req.get('referer') but that was returning null. Can I access this information in any other way? Please help

Comment: It is not unexpected for the referrer to sometimes be null (or always, in the case of all requests coming in from a client that doesn't send one)

Comment: Hi @Meera, was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick test for the same situation you're handling, it works without any issue.

It was tested with: `curl “<FUNCTION_ URL>” --referer "https://google.com"`

And to get the request header, I used: `req.get(‘Referrer’)`

Have in mind that if the URL is not valid, the result would be undefined, as follows:

[image]

If the solution provided still does not work, it might be an issue with your request to Cloud Functions.